# Angular (ionic) update expression in view after http post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to update the expression in my view after a http post request. I heard you could use the $scope.$apply function. This doesn't work because I get an error from ionic.bundle.js "$digest already in progress". Am i doing this wrong or is it an error from ionic?

## View

```
<ion-view title="Signup" id="page8">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
    <form id="signup-form2" ng-controller="signupCtrl" method="post" class="list">
        <label class="item item-input" id="signup-input5">
          <span class="input-label">Password:</span>
          <input type="password" required="required" ng-model="passwordField" placeholder="">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input" id="signup-input7">
          <span class="input-label">Confirm Password:</span>
          <input type="password" required="required" ng-model="confirmPasswordField" placeholder="">
        </label>
      </ion-list>
      <div ng-controller="signupCtrl">
        {{textveld}}
      </div>
      <button id="signup-button3" class="button button-stable button-block" ng-click="details()" ng-model="submitButton" ng-controller="signupCtrl" >Sign up</button>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

## Controller

```
.controller('signupCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$stateParams', '$timeout',  // The following is the constructor function for this page's controller. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller
// You can include any angular dependencies as parameters for this function
// TIP: Access Route Parameters for your page via $stateParams.parameterName
function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $timeout) {
// Signup page functions

 $scope.textveld = 'Hallo!';

    $scope.details = function(){
        if($scope.passwordField === $scope.confirmPasswordField) {
            $http.post('[MY URL]',{
                    username: $scope.usernameField,
                    email: $scope.emailField,
                    password: $scope.passwordField
                }
            )
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.contents = response.data;
                console.log($scope.contents);
                //THIS DOESN'T WORK
                $scope.textveld = response.data;
                //$scope.$apply(); 
            });
        }
        else {
            $scope.textveld = "Passwords do not match";

        }

    };
}])
```

Comment: Why you are initiializing `ng-controller` multiple time? - this is wrong. Either place your `ng-controller` in root element or mention your controller in state definition for your view. Each `ng-controller` holds a unique `$scope` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while doing `ajax` request, use $timeout to prevent multi `$digest` problem.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.$appply(function() {
    // do things here.
  })
})
```

Note: you have to inject $timeout first.

Comment: I've changed it like this but it still doesn't work:

`.then(function(response) {
                                $scope.contents = response.data;
                                console.log($scope.contents);

                                $timeout(function() {
                                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                                        $scope.textveld = response.data;
                                    })
                                });

                            });`

Comment: @L.Coomans can you post what you got from response.data please?

Comment: I got my correct response, what is a string which is being returned via an echo from the php document, which I am posting to.

Comment: Oh, and yes I am encoding the information with json_encode if you wonder.

Comment: @L.Coomans you have a problem with your code that you should remove the ng-controller statement which wraps the {{textveld}}.